# Shell PATH to R under macOS Big Sur

Tags: r, bash, macos, shell, rstudio

I have a problem with R CMD under Big Sur. I installed R via default .pkg (not via brew) and I have been using zsh (Z shell) as the default shell. I think that I have a problem with PATH that I am not able to fix.

In Terminal:

```
~ echo $0  
zsh  
~ echo $PATH             
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Users/vanderleidebastiani/.jenv/bin:/opt/miniconda3/bin:/opt/miniconda3/condabin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources  
~ R CMD  
looks ok
```

In R/RStudio:

```
> system("echo $0")
sh
> system("echo $PATH")  
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/postback  
> system("R CMD")  
sh: R: command not found
Warning message:
In system("R CMD") : error in running command
```

I can solve this temporarily with **Sys.getenv** if I include the PATH to "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")  
"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/postback" 
 
Sys.setenv(PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/postback:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources")  

system("R CMD")  
-looks ok
```

I tried to include the PATH permanently, so I edited **.bash_profile**, **.profile**, **.zshrc**, **.bashrc** in my home folder (in case "/Users/vanderleidebastiani") to include:

```
# Setting PATH for R
export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
```

However, it does not make any effect. The PATH does not recognize after I restart R, it goes back to initial settings.

Do I need to include PATH in another file or I made some mistake in the way to include it?

Best, Vanderlei

Comment: Have you closed and reopened RStudio? Also, what is the purpose of running `system("R CMD") ` ? (aside from demonstrating that it's not found) i.e. what problems does it cause you - is it when you go to build a package or something like that?

Comment: @stevec I have closed and reopened R and RStudio. I have a problem with MODIS package (I have opened an issue in https://github.com/MatMatt/MODIS/issues/104) and I think that the problems can be related.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling R/RStudio?

Comment: @steve I come from macOS Catalina > change the default shell  > Update to Big Sur > remove completely R and RStudio (to try to fix MODIS problem) and reinstall R e RStudio. I use another computer with Big Sur and then MODIS works fine after the last MODIS update, and the R CMD also works fine (that is why I think the problems can be related).

Answer (score 7):

To create a new path just do this in MACOS Big Sur

1. sudo touch ~/.zshrc
2. sudo nano export PATH=$PATH:/YOUR PATH
3. crtl + x and save
4. source ~/.zshrc or close and open the terminal

Check with echo $PATH

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with access to homebrew installed binaries. The fix I found was to modify the global PATH variable in Big Sur.

It turns out if you drop a text file into the /etc/paths.d folder it will be parsed and added to PATH even after a restart of RStudio.

I used `sudo nano /etc/paths.d/homebrew` to add a text file and pasted in `/opt/homebrew/bin` and `/opt/homebrew/sbin` on separate lines. After saving and closing I rebooted RStudio and ran `echo $PATH` from RStudio's terminal to check that the path had been imported correctly.

Ref:
https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-do-i-set-the-global-path-environment-variable-on-os-x